# How could I code so that angular ui-router's ui-sref to work?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-ui, angular-ui-router

I have written a demo code for ui-router but getting error
like: `unknown attribute 'ui-sref`

I go through from the source: ([How to get angular ui-router's ui-sref to work, when inside a directive's template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647782/how-to-get-angular-ui-routers-ui-sref-to-work-when-inside-a-directives-templa)).

But, still I did not correct it.

my code is:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script <script src="lib/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="helloworld.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-app="helloworld">
  <a ui-sref="hello" ui-sref-active="active">Hello</a<a ui-sref="about" ui-sref-active="active">About</a>
  <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

**helloworld.js**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }
  var aboutState = {
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
  }
  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in your HTML document. Also, `<script>` tags should go inside the `<head>` or `<body>` tags and most certainly not outside the `<html>` tag

Comment: I fixed it and it is working.